# campo calculado de conversion de inversion usd a clp por mes en data studio

Tags: google-data-studio

Estoy trabajando un campo calculado en data studio con la fuente de datos Display y Video360, el campo calculado al que quiero llegar es la inversión en pesos (clp), ya que la fuente trae la inversión es usd, el valor del dólar varía mes a mes según lo que nos informen de finanzas.

El problema que ocurre con esta fuente es que la inversión en usd es una métrica de agregación automática, mientras que la fecha (transformada a número) es una dimensión tipo número no agregada, esto genera que data studio no me deje guardar el campo calculado.

Al intentar darle agregación a la fecha con SUM me da el resultado que espero, sin embargo, no tengo el resultado del total.

También intenté crear el campo calculado en una tabla dentro del mismo informe y no tengo este problema de agregación, pero al hacerlo así no tengo la posibilidad de crear mas campos calculados con este campo calculado de inversión en pesos (por ejemplo, coste por mil impresiones o costo por clic)

**¿Es posible tener este campo calculado en data studio a nivel fuente de datos y que incluya también el total al momento de crear una tabla o una tarjeta de resultados en un informe?**

Les comparto formula del campo calculado y como queda al visualizarlo en un informe:

**CASE

 WHEN SUM(MC_fecha) = 202112 THEN Revenue (Advertiser Currency) * 860

 WHEN SUM(MC_fecha) = 202201 THEN Revenue (Advertiser Currency) * 890 
 ELSE 0

 END**

[image: tabla en un informe de data studio]

Sus experiencias me ayudarían mucho!
Gracias

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. Te recomiendo que coloques como texto el código. Puedes leer [ask] para mas información. Saludos

Comment: Hola Andres, gracias por la recomendación